# Binding и SetOnClickListner в Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, onclicklistener, android-data-binding

Необходимо сделать следующее: с помощью binding найти кнопку, которая будет отвечать за сохранение данных, введенных в EditText, используя обработчик setOnClickListner Я примерное понимаю как это делать, но все равно затрудняюсь как это прописать.

Comment: Вы описали довольно сложную логику с множеством шагов. С каким именно шагом у вас затруднения? С подключением библиотеки?

Comment: Трудности возникают при попытке повешать обработчик на EditText

Comment: Судя по вашему описанию, вам надо на какую-то кнопку вешать слушатель, а не на поле ввода. Возможно поможет, если вы код покажете